# ZPL: (00) in human readable but not in barcode

Tags: barcode, zebra-printers, zpl, barcode-printing, gs1-128

I am trying to create a GS1-128 barcode using ZPL. The barcode should have parenthesis automatically filled in at the start of the human readable before and after the first two digits.
In other words, I would like to send a SSCC-18 string like this: "00206739780661776353", the human readable should show "(00)206739780661776353" and the barcode should read "00206739780661776353".

This is my code so far:

```
^XA

^FO360,630^BY2^A0N,30,30^BCN,100,Y,Y,N,D^FD00206739780661776353^FS

^XZ
```

If I manually input "^FD(00)206739780661776353^FS", the "(00)" shows in the human readable,  but not in the barcode, which is what I want, but I am struggling to get the parenthesis around the first two digits automatically. Is there a way to do this in ZPL?

Any help or tips on where to look would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: With SSCC-18, the parentheses are _not_ part of the barcoded value - they are only for the human readable text.  Mode-D automatically adds the ^FNC1 prefix to the barcode, which tells the reader that the data is UCC/GS1 encoded.  Put the parentheses back into the ^FD string.  Then use a scanner that can properly read a GS1 barcode.  The typical readers on phones (usually zxing based) drop/ignore the ^FNC1 character.

Comment: Twenty-three years ago (yes, in 1997,) I asked Zebra to produce the standard-formatted human-readable line for SSCC & EAN-128,centred about the barcode. They replied that SSCC and Code-128 were the same thing and ignored further correspondence. It would appear that you need to generate each independently.